# How to link a PHP file to a html button

Tags: php, html, sql, anchor

I want to load a php file when the user clicks on the button, but it isn't working and php file is not loaded. Is there any way to link the php file to the button via anchor tag?

`<a href="visual.php"  >
<button name="visual" id="newbtn" >Add Visual device</button></a>`


`<a href="audio.php" ><button name="audio"  id="newbtn" >Add Audio device</button></a>`

I need to create a main html page which includes only two buttons and when "Add Visual device" button is clicked a php page is loaded with a form to add details about the device to visual device table in sql database. When the "Add Audio device" button is clicked it need to load the php page with form to send the data to the audio table in the db. But nothing loads when the buttons are clicked... I want to load the two pages when the respective buttons are clicked

Comment: What does the code that you posted do? What doesn't it do? Provide details as to what's happening so others can provide more focused feedback.

Comment: I need to create a main html page which includes two buttons and when "Add Visual device" button is clicked a php page is loaded with a form to add details about the device to visual device table in sql database. When the "Add Audio device" button is clicked it need to load the php page with form to send the data to the audio table in the db. But nothing loads when the buttons are clicked...  I want to load the two pages when the respective buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code to hit php file through anchor tag.

```html
<html>
<body>

<a href="audio.php">visit php file</a>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the code to hit php file through button.

```html
<form action="audio.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="Open Form">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding `onclick` event as follows

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'audio.php';">Add Audio device</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'visual.php';">Add Visual device</button>

//It can be useful when you are not using a <form> tag.
```